# Timestring regex: please simplify it and show how the colons can be dropped?

Tags: python, regex

I have written a regex expression to parse the system date and time and I can capture all with this script ( I know there are modules to parse date, this is only for regex learning)

```
import re
s = "Sun Oct 14 13:47:03 CEST 2012"
x = r"([A-Za-z]+\b)\s([A-Za-z]+\b)\s(\d\d)\s(\d\d)([/:])(\d\d)([/:])(\d\d)\s([A-Za-z]+\b)\s(\d\d\d\d)"
toll = (re.search(x,s))

for i in range(11):
    print (toll.group(i))
```

**Objective:**

> To get all the individual elements in groups

**Questions:**

1. How can I make my regex expression simpler (if there is any way)?
2. How can I simply drop the colon from my regex expression (Like I dont want : to be captured at all)?

Here's my output:

```
Sun Oct 14 13:47:03 CEST 2012  
Sun  
Oct  
14  
13  
:  
47  
:  
03  
CEST  
2012
```

Comment: I am sure that python already has libraries that parse dates. No need to re-invent them with a regex.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I know , but I am trying to learn regex and practice. Can you help ?

Comment: @Fenomatik like Hunter says it's going to be a lot easier and more maintainable to parse in with the time&date function, then write it back out in whatever string format you like. Do you still really want to write a raw regex, just for learning regexes?

Comment: `I dont want : to be captured` - Then why do you explicitly request it to be captured?

Comment: @smci , You think its a bad idea to try out with parsing date and time to learn regex ?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I have reduced/simplified my regex to this 
x = r"([\S]+\b)\s([\S]+\b)\s([\d]{2})\s([\d]{2})([/:])([\d]{2})([/:])([\d]{2})\s([\S]+\b)\s([\d]{4})"
But as you said why request it when i dont want it , The thing is if I dont look for it , it wont find the next character which in this case is 47.

Comment: @Fenomatik: it's a bad idea in the real world to solve a non-problem, especially when hundreds/thousands of man-years have already been spent on producing a reliable, portable, well-maintained standard. If you want to learn regexes, why not pick something harder and less standardized, e.g. a regex for US postal addresses, or Canadian addresses, or European phone numbers.

Comment: Fenomatik: anyway this entire regex can be avoided by simply doing `re.split(r'[ :/]', s)`, per my answer. Split on whitespace or colon or slash.

Comment: @smci , Thanks for the suggestion i'll work on it ASAP , but this one is just bothering me :(

Comment: Also, your match-group for timezone `([A-Za-z]+\b)` will break on e.g. `UTC+8` (or even `UTC+08:00`). Regexes like these are always a tradeoff between compromising readability for getting a long but watertight (and fast-parsing) regex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93023/discussion-between-fenomatik-and-smci).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: simply don't put parentheses around the groups matching colons, then they won't show up as capture groups:

```
>>> x = r"([A-Za-z]+\b)\s([A-Za-z]+\b)\s(\d\d)\s(\d\d)[/:](\d\d)[/:](\d\d)\s([A-Za-z]+\b)\s(\d\d\d\d)"
>>> re.search(x,s).groups()

('Sun', 'Oct', '14', '13', '47', '03', 'CEST', '2012')
```

But if you really want to simplify this big regex, it looks like you can get by with simply regex-splitting on space or colon, and avoid the big regex entirely:

```
>>> re.split(r'[ :/]', s)

['Sun', 'Oct', '14', '13', '47', '03', 'CEST', '2012']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put parenthesis around a statement, it becomes a "capturing group".
To prevent this, either don't place brackets, or create a non-capturing group:

```
(?:[a-z]*)
```

However, my solution would be:

```
([A-Za-z]+)\s([A-Za-z]+)\s(\d\d)\s(\d\d)[/:](\d\d)[/:](\d\d)\s([A-Za-z]+)\s(\d{4})
```

Note that I removed the word boundaries, as they are irrelevant, due to the condition before them being only the alphabet, followed by a space character.

I also unbracketed the colons, and specified the number of digits on the last statement, with `{4}`

Comment: Also, you could try this `([A-Za-z]+)\s([A-Za-z]+)(?:\s(\d\d)){2}(?:[/:](\d\d)){2}\s([A-Za-z]+)\s(\d{4})`, but I don't know if it will break it into groups properly.

Comment: I tried to simply this , you think it looks better now ?
    x = r"(\S+\b)\s(\S+\b)\s(\d{2})\s(\d{2})[/:](\d{2})[/:](\d{2})\s(\S+\b)\s(\d{4})"

Comment: It's simpler, but easier to get bad data in there. \S is a non-space character, meaning it will match things like 6 and ♥.

Comment: There is no way to simply avoid it ? (Not adding it to the regex or not even write a non-capturing group)